# How to connect to a CentOS VM over ftp?

Tags: centos, ftp

Host - *Windows 7*

Guest - *CentOS*

I have installed `vsftpd` as according to this [guide](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=ftp) and the service is running. But when I try to connect to the VM from the host using FileZilla the connection times out

```
Connecting to 192.168.22.128:21...
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

My host can ping 192.168.22.128 no trouble and I can view web pages served by the VM in the browser of my host too.

What else do I need to do to connect via ftp?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an issue with the firewall blocking port 21 on the VM. After allowing the port through the firewall as instructed [here](http://www.unixmen.com/install-configure-ftp-server-centos-7/) I can connect using FileZilla on my host machine.

<strike>I am yet to actually see if transferring files is successful though.</strike> File transfer is successful after also adding the user I log in as to the group with write permissions in the directory I want to upload files to.